# How to use partially the computed property name on a type definition

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I need to define the type for a React component that receives a prop `name` (that should be a value of `Fields`) and any others props.

So I tried something like that

```
type Fields = 'address' | 'recipientName' | 'recipientPhone';

type Props = {
  name: Fields
  [key in string]: any // error here
};
```

But it isn't working. I'm receiving this error:

> A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.

How can I create this type?

Comment: change `[key in string]` to `[key: string]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) syntax, not the normal dictionary syntax. Try this:

```js
type Fields = 'address' | 'recipientName' | 'recipientPhone';

type Props = {
  name: Fields
  [key: string]: any // All good
};
```

That's probably what you're looking for. However, if you did actually want to use mapped types for some reason, plus separate keys, you need to define two types and intersection them, like so:

```js
type Fields = 'address' | 'recipientName' | 'recipientPhone';

type Props = {
  name: Fields
} & {
  [key in string]: any // All good
};
```

You only need that if the `key in string` or `any` is going to become something more complicated though.